# AS3 preloader class error 1120: access of undefined property e. [Please Help]

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have some issues with my preloader class. everytime I try to run the MovieClip it gives me 4 errors of 1120: access of undefined property e. I dont know what the problem is.

package  {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.text.*;

public class loadingScene extends MovieClip {

    public var percentLoad:Number = Math.round(e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal * 100);

    public function loadingScene() {
        stop();
        this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
    }


    public function onProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void {
        loader_txt.text = Math.round(e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal *100)+ "%";
        if (percentLoad == 100){
            onLoaded();
        }

    }

    function onLoaded() {
        this.loaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
        trace("YES"); 
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete where you initialize percentLoad. e does not exist at that point in time, thus its undefined. Also you didn't define e anywhere, but MovieClip thinks you did.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.text.*;

public class loadingScene extends MovieClip {

    public var percentLoad:Number = 0;

    public function loadingScene() {
        stop();
        this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
    }


    public function onProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void {
        percentLoad = Math.round(e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal * 100);
        loader_txt.text = percentLoad+ "%";
        if (percentLoad == 100){
            onLoaded();
        }

    }

    function onLoaded() {
        this.loaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
        trace("YES"); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Hm it fires 2 errors 1067 & 1188 on percentLoad:Number = Math.round(e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal * 100);

Comment: bytesTotal is a property of the timer object, or is it bytesLoaded?

Comment: there is no Timer only a progressEvent. when i fire the movie it gives me 1067:implict coercion of a value of type Number to an unrelated type class [AND] 188: Illegal assignment to class Number.

Comment: Now it fires Error #1009 Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. sorry for the trouble buddy and thanx for the help.

Comment: No problem. I like to help. loader_txt is not defined anywhere. add a public var loader_txt : TextField = new TextField(); then add addChild( loader_txt ); before you addEventListener.